# How would Roman Warfare have changed if they actually had legendary 'flexible glass', and it was cost-effective?

Tags: society, alternate-history

How would Roman Warfare have changed if they actually had legendary 'flexible glass', and it was cost-effective?

[Flexible Glass (vitrum flexile)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_glass)

It's an unbreakable, and I mean **literally** unbreakable, glass. Assume that it looks and acts like normal Roman glass, so an enemy could melt a hole through it, if they wanted, and can be made at about the same price, but it just can't shatter, and instead dents like brass. If you can make glass, you can make vitrum flexile, with just the addition of some additive, which Rome won't run out of.

Could you make city walls out of the stuff?

Comment: I don't know if they'd have made armor of that stuff. I mean, how exactly is flexible glass better suited for armor than plain old iron/steel? It would easily become the Roman's equivalent of PET bottles, though.

Comment: Isn't that just plastic?

Comment: @Samuel - I guess, yeah. ... Has there been a question like "What if Romans had plastic?" to say this as a duplicate of? Or are there any other objections I should iron out?

Comment: @Malandy I think that's an *excellent* question. It's not a duplicate, I just hadn't heard of "flexible glass". I would only recommend that you narrow your scope, ask about one faucet of roman society that has this material.

Comment: @Samuel - Alright! Now it's focused on Warfare!

Comment: Wow, that's a sad story about the inventor! But, pretty common in those days I'd imagine.

Comment: I'm not sure this would have much of an effect to be honest. While it is unbreakable, it sounds like it still dented which means blunt weapons would still be effective. Especially in some variants of the story where the glassmaker fixed the glass with their hands.

Comment: How 'unbreakable' is it? Can it be punctured by arrows? Can nothing ever penetrate a sheet of it? (i.e. bend but never break). If I make a thin foil out of it, will that protect me from all edged weapons?

Comment: @ckersch - Literally Unbreakable, but will dent like brass, so it's got the malleability of brass, so its sort of like clear unbreakable brass?

Comment: Maybe he just invented jello...

Comment: Having had thrown rocks bounce off of it for riot control and not break is one thing.  Having it not be chopped to pieces in minutes by a battle axe or sword in combat is another thing entirely. Shields are complicated things, not just circles of wood.

Comment: @Oldcat - Did you mean to post on the Riot Shield Answer? 'Cause while *Vitrum Flexile* can be bashed into a shape that is useless for defense, it can't be made useless any other way. ... Except by incineration of some kind...

Answer (score 7):

As has been said, it's just armor.  Why would you bother with making something like city walls out of it?

Now, there's one thing worth making out of it--helmets.  Back then you could choose protection or visibility, not both--and even if you chose protection you could die of something through the eye slit.  A helmet of this material would have no eye slit.

Answer (score 6):

[image: Riot shield]

Since one of the Romans preferred fighting techniques were the [shieldwall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shield_wall), a large improvement would be to have a shield that you could see through. Giving the opportunity grab the opponent and stab him, so on and so forth.

Comment: The Romans did not use a phalanx.  They were in a formation with short swords and shields

Comment: The roman name was Testudo the principles was the same, your shield covers your own left side and your partners right side you use the right hand to attack with spear or short sword, and pull enemies in to the third row that would stab the person pulled, the second row would support the shield wall against breaches and hold the shield at top to cover against head blows and arrow rains.

Comment: The testudo is a special assault formation versus forts, not for combat with other infantry - the shields are overhead, for one thing.  The phalanx is a deep, square formation, with the soldiers armed with 15-20 foot spears so that many ranks can extend the spearpoints out the front of the formation.  The Legion's arrangement and armament is diffferent.

Comment: The shieldwall is not a roman formation either - it is used by dark ages army, notably the Anglo Saxon ones.  You could look over the wall normally, as the sheld was below your face except when blocking.

Answer (score 3):

It might make a reasonable material for armor. It would presumably not rust, so it would be easier to maintain than iron or steel armor. It would also presumably be lighter and less likely to break.

So, "**more armor**"?

It might also be useful for creating armoured warships with lower drag than with wood, but I doubt it would have occurred to the Romans. While their naval technology was probably decent, they had several centuries of minimal need for improving their warships. Maybe if somebody had realized that making the entire ship of the glass would make it have **much** longer lifetime and possibly make up for the higher initial cost.

Comment: The glass is literally unbreakable. You can bend and melt it though...

Answer (score 2):

They could pound it into various useful forms such as magnifying lenses, then assemble them into telescopes to see the enemy at a distance.

Glass is nearly invisible underwater, so sharpened spikes of flexible glass mounted in all of the shallow points on a river would effectively block and possibly maim anyone trying to ford across.  The same thing could be done along any ocean or lake shorelines.

Comment: Would the literal unbreakability impact the sharpening of the vitrum flexile spikes?

Comment: If you can melt it or mold it  you can sharpen it that way. It doesn't need to have a razor edge to be dangerous.

Comment: And they couldn't find their way across by probing with sticks?

Comment: Glass is invisible underwater only if it has the same refractive index as the water - which is typically not the case.  Hard to see, maybe, but *not* invisible.

Comment: Good point.  I have edited my answer

Comment: Making lenses would require knowledge of lenscraft, which I don't believe the Romans had. It also requires a high degree of precision, which I'm not sure would be as attainable with pounding as it is with grinding. If anything, flexible glass seems like it would be worse for making lenses than regular glass is.

Comment: Also, there is nothing to say the glass was optically superior to glass Romans had. Which probably was not good enough for telescopes. The raw materials were not clean enough, I think.

Answer (score 2):

### Walls

As a wall it would be decently strong if you put a barrier of some kind behind it you could easily make it similar to a normal wall.  Although unbreakable doesn't mean it cannot be either dug under or scaled so it wouldn't make much of a difference.

### Armor

As armor there are a few interesting thing you could do with this. As someone mentioned before, a see through helm would be a great tool. Honestly though why stop there? a see through shield would be a great tool as well. The main problem would be that the user of the armor could still be killed. there would have to be breaks in the armor to allow for mobility and the fact that it dents means that a blunt weapon could be an effective means of countering this armor to some degree. having unbreakable armor like this could mean that certain tactics like the phalanx (basically a wall of spears to counter cavalry and charging armies.) would be much less effective.

### weapons

Having see through spike in shallow water is a good idea but to expand further on that idea previously mentioned by Henry it might be an effective means of guarding coastal cities from naval invasions. Weapons made from this materiel would probably be as good as any other metal they had at their time considering how it bends. It may be a better option to stick with steel swords.

All in all it is a strong defensive choice but not necessarily a strong offensive choice.

Comment: A glass wall can have a opaque barrier behind it...

Comment: You could double layer the walls I suppose.

Comment: Edit that in, then?